# cassandra IndexSummaryManagerTest unit test case timeout error

Tags: unit-testing, build, cassandra

I have been an error while compiling cassandra unit test cases. One of the tests gets timed out sometimes. While https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8981 states that this issue has been resolved in version 2.1.5, I am still getting this issue. Building cassandra 2.1.5 from source using jdk1.8. Below are the details:

```
[junit] Testsuite: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexSummaryManagerTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] 
[junit] Testcase: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexSummaryManagerTest:testCompactionRace:   Caused an ERROR
[junit] Timeout occurred. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the timeout.
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Timeout occurred. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the timeout.
[junit]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[junit] 
[junit] 
[junit] Test org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexSummaryManagerTest FAILED (timeout)
[junit] Testsuite: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexSummaryTest
[junit] Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.193 sec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to participate in Cassandra testing discussions is probably on the IRC channel #cassandra-dev on irc.freenode.net [0] - the Cassandra developers and test engineers all hang out there and discuss this sort of thing daily :) I just happen to browse the Cassandra tag here occasionally and have caught your last few recent test questions.

With regards to your particular test error, I took a quick look at recent CI history [1] and do not see any recent timeouts - that doesn't mean the test can't be improved with your help, if you have found a problem.

I'm not sure why type of system you are testing on, but perhaps the I/O is slow, which could make the test take longer than the default 60 second test timeout. Start by setting the timeout in build.xml higher to see if the test at least eventually passes - let's double it:

```
(cassandra-2.1 *)mshuler@hana:~/git/cassandra$ git diff
diff --git a/build.xml b/build.xml
index e197696..2d5e20a 100644
--- a/build.xml
+++ b/build.xml
@@ -91,7 +91,7 @@
     <property name="maven-repository-url" value="https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots"/>
     <property name="maven-repository-id" value="apache.snapshots.https"/>

-    <property name="test.timeout" value="60000" />
+    <property name="test.timeout" value="120000" />
     <property name="test.long.timeout" value="600000" />

     <!-- default for cql tests. Can be override by -Dcassandra.test.use_prepared=false -->
```

Build and test again (output snipped):

```
(cassandra-2.1 *)mshuler@hana:~/cassandra$ ant clean jar
<...>
(cassandra-2.1 *)mshuler@hana:~/cassandra$ ant test -Dtest.name=IndexSummaryManagerTest
<...>
testlist:
     [echo] running test bucket 0 tests
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/mshuler/cassandra/build/test/cassandra
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/mshuler/cassandra/build/test/output
    [junit] WARNING: multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit 
    [junit]          jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
    [junit]      and jar:file:/home/mshuler/cassandra/build/lib/jars/ant-1.6.5.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
    [junit] Testsuite: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexSummaryManagerTest
    [junit] Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 14.737 sec
    [junit] 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 18 seconds
```

If you still have problems, take a look at the test system.log file and see if you can sort out what your problem might be. You'll find that log file at `build/test/logs/system.log`.

If you can identify a problem and can provide reproduction steps, open a JIRA ticket...in fact, it looks like I re-opened a different JIRA for this test timing out during the test-all ant target: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9271

I will go ahead and post this answer, since the above are at least a couple tools you should have in your test toolbox. Feel free to come chat on IRC, though!

[0] http://freenode.net/

[1] http://cassci.datastax.com/job/cassandra-2.1_utest/lastCompletedBuild/testReport/org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable/IndexSummaryManagerTest/history/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I kept on increasing the timeout and the test finally succeeded and it took 6 mins for the test to succeed. I am running it in a docker which runs on a VM on my mac. As you suggested, I will join the IRC channel and get inputs from there as well.

Comment: Also, I have noticed these lines being repeated in the log for a major portion of the test execution time: 
DEBUG [pool-3-thread-1] 2015-05-19 18:16:07,136 Completed resizing of index summaries; current approximate memory used: 0.09203243255615234 MB 
DEBUG [pool-3-thread-2] 2015-05-19 18:16:07,137 Completed resizing of index summaries; current approximate memory used: 0.09203243255615234 MB 
DEBUG [pool-3-thread-1] 2015-05-19 18:16:07,137 Beginning redistribution of index summaries for 65 sstables with memory pool size 7 MB; current spaced used is 0.09203243255615234 MB